# Extract argument of function from string with R

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse

Preferably using the `stringr` package, I want to create a function `extract()` that takes for argument a vector of strings

```
vec <- c(
"div(span(icon(\"hospital-user\"), i18n$t(\"Enrolments\"), \"or\", i18n$t(\"Paper\"))),",
"a string with no matching pattern",
"Lala i18n$t(\"Rock\")"
)
```

and return all elements inside `i18n$t(\""\)`.

In the above example, `extract(vec)` would return `"Enrolments"`, `"Paper"`, `"Rock"`.

Comment: Some people voted that the question "Needs more focus - if your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format.
This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."
I can't understand why.

Comment: They probably meant "Needs details or clarity", as you haven't actually asked a question, nor shown any effort to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround to extract the word (`\\w+`) that follows a the `n$t("`.  The `$` is metacharacter, so just escape (`\\`) it

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(vec, '(?<=n\\$t\\(")\\w+')[[1]]
[1] "Enrolments" "Paper"      "Rock"
```

If there are more than one element, use `unlist`

```
unlist(str_extract_all(vec, '(?<=n\\$t\\(")\\w+'))
```

Comment: Perfect, just do the unlisting to have the solution:
`str_extract_all(vec, '(?<=n\\$t\\(")\\w+') |> unlist()`

Comment: As it is a single list element, you can directly extract wth `[[1]]`

Comment: I have `> str_extract_all(vec, '(?<=n\\$t\\(")\\w+')[[1]]`

`"Enrolments" "Paper"` without `Rock`

Comment: @tic-toc-choc i used `"div(span(icon(\"hospital-user\"), i18n$t(\"Enrolments\"), \"or\", i18n$t(\"Paper\"))),\",\n\"a string with no matching pattern\"\n\"Lala i18n$t(\"Rock\")"` as `vec`

Comment: Probably because you may have 2 elements instead of the single element I used as vec